# Convert variable into array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I use `<pre>`to display my variable `echo $value_detail_final;`

it displays a proper file like this

```
    {
        "companies": [
        {
        "id": "4127303000000527195",
        "company_name": "235 St Georges Landowning Trust & Australian City Properties Pty Ltd"
        },
        {
        "id": "4127303000004495043",
        "company_name": "Bourke Junction No 1 Pty Ltd"
        },
        {
        "id": "4127303000000527189",
        "company_name": "Brookfield Commercial Operations Pty Ltd"
        } 
       ]
    }
```

But when I use something like this `$value_detail_final[0]` it displays  `{` 
if `$value_detail_final[1]` its `"`, its like displaying each character on my variable .

even foreach doesnt work, by the way this is from json file and I use `json_decode` file.

How can I able to put each of the id and company_name into a variable so I can use them ?

This is how I decode my json file based on the given sturcture

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("response.json");

$array = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    // echo "Key:".$key."<br>";
    if($key=='details')
    {
        foreach ($value as $key_detail => $detail)
        {

            if($key_detail=='userMessage')
            {
                foreach ($detail as $key_detail_final => $value_detail_final)
                {
                    print_r($value_detail_final);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it is double encoded or something `[0]` is the first character of a string and that's what you get `{`.  Show what you get and how you decode it and what is the result.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I added my decode function

Comment: @catcon so I will twice json_decode() ?

Comment: @all I already added my json_decode function

Comment: This makes no sense, there is no `userMessage` and the code doesn't match with what you say you want to do.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ill include sa json file so you can understand better wait

Comment: It looks like `$value_detail_final` is also a JSON string so you need to set `$value_detail_final = json_decode($value_detail_final, true);`